# undefinded reference to 'function' c++

Tags: c++, function, reference, undefined, codeblocks

I'm working with Code::Blocks in C++.

I have the three folowing files :

main.cpp

```
#include "functions.hpp"

int main()
{
    getSourceCode("str1","str2");
    return 0;
}
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "functions.hpp"

void getSourceCode(string str1,string str2)
{
}
```

functions.hpp

```
void getSourceCode(string, string);
```

And I got the error `'undefined reference to 'getSourceCode(std::string, std::string)'` for the line number 5 in main.cpp

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Are you linking `functions.cpp`?

Comment: functions.hpp to functions.cpp

Comment: Thanks I added `#include "functions.cpp"` in functions.hpp I didn't know I had to do this, but it works

Comment: @Drakalex: No, **do not do that!!**

Comment: Why ? It's working, what is the good way to do it ?

Comment: See @wolfPack88 comment.

Comment: Injecting nutrients into your body rectally "works", but it's not my preferred way to consume food. YMMV

Comment: Inluding != linking. See the linked question of course.

Comment: Oh okay, but what do you mean by linking ? It's not inside code but inside the C::B right ?

Comment: @Drakalex: What is preventing you from reading the duplicate question and its answers? And, come to think of it, your C++ book?

Comment: READ THE LINKED QUESTION. It's a duplicate for a reason

Comment: (And, yes, that's right)

Comment: I didn't see the linked question sorry, I successfully linked the file, thanks for your help

Comment: @Drakalex: Glad you got it fixed! And not rectally!!